# Using a batch script, copy only those files that match a certain string in file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find a way to find, then copy to a new folder, files that are marked with a certain date stamp.
My folder structure is like this:

> D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\2021-12-31\ D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\2022-01-01
> D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\2022-01-02\ D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\2022-01-03\

Within each of those folders are files such as this

> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T140020Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T143020Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T150019Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T153020Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T160020Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T160018Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T170020Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T173019Z.jpg
> GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220101T180020Z.jpg etcetera

What I need is a command line(s) for a batch script to find each file starting on a certain date, with only the "T1700" timestamp, then copy that file to a new folder.

this is what I have tried:

```
for /R "D:\GOES DATA CENTER\goes16\fd\CUSTOMLUT\" %%f in (*.jpg) do xcopy "%%f" "F:\SatelliteInput\CUSTOMLUT\compositeFC" /D /D:%startdate%
```

This solution has worked for what I need; using Variables for %satellite%, %bandtype% and %startdate% - I'll add a user defined variable for the time as well later.

```
for /R "D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\goes%satellite%\fd\%bandtype%\" %%f in (*T1700*.jpg) do xcopy "%%f" "D:\TEMPPROCESSING\HIGHNOON" /D /D:%startdate% /S /C /Y
```

Comment: `xcopy /?` should answer your question.

Comment: This is what I use to search by file date with startdate as a variable I set:

 for /R "D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\goes16\fd\CUSTOMLUT\" %%f in (*.jpg) do xcopy "%%f" "F:\SatelliteInput\CUSTOMLUT\compositeFC" /D /D:%startdate%

How could I modify that to just search for those file with the T1700 only?

Comment: With this a trial @Echo OFF

 Set "Pattern=T1700"

 For /R "D:\GOES  DATA CENTER\" %%# in (*.jpg) Do (
  Echo %%~nx# | FIND "GOES16_FD_FC_CUSTOMLUT_20220102%Pattern%0020Z" 1>NUL && (
   Set /A "Index+=1"
   Call Set "JPG%%INDEX%%=%%~#"
   Echo Full Path: %%~#
   Echo FileName : %%~nx#
   REM Echo Directory: %%~p#
  )
 )

 ::CLS
 Echo JPG1 = %JPG1%
 Echo JPG2 = %JPG2%

 Pause&Exit

Comment: @CarlReinemann Why do you use the wildcard pattern `*.jpg` in set of command __FOR__ if you want to find and copy just `*T1700???.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate each folder within the root folder:

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\GOES DATA CENTER" %%i in ("*T1700???.jpg") do copy "%%~i" "D:\destination folder\"
```

or to do only folders you define in a list:

```
@echo off
set "dirs="D:\GOES DATA CENTER\2021-12-31" "D:\GOES DATA CENTER\2022-01-01" "D:\GOES DATA CENTER\2022-01-02" "D:\GOES DATA CENTER\2022-01-03""
for %%i in (%dirs%) do copy "%%~i\*T1700???.jpg" "destination folder"
```

Comment: This assumes that the filenames are unique across all subdirectories. They probably are if the date is part of the filename. If not, then the subdirectory structure would need to be replicated in the destination.

Comment: @lit, yes, but I am just going on what OP has given as examples in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think I found a solution that seems to work and will add it to the bottom of my post